# Get percentage based on groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
subject bool Count
1   False   329232  
1   True    73896   
2   False   268338  
2   True    76424   
3   False   186167  
3   True    27078   
4   False   172417  
4   True    113268
```

I would like to turn `Count` into percents for each subject group. So for example, row 1  would be `329232 / (329232 + 73896)   = 0.816` and row 2 would be `73896/ (329232 + 73896) = 0.183`. Then the total would change for group 2, and so on.

Is this possible to do by a groupby? I tried iterating over the rows with little success.

Comment: Is there any chance this was created with a `.value_counts()` in the first place? You can specify `normalize=True` in that case to get the exact output you want

Comment: No, this is where it came from - maybe this helps? `df.groupby(['subject', 'bool']).count().reset_index()`

Comment: Then instead do `df.groupby('subject').bool.value_counts(normalize=True)`

Comment: This worked, thanks!

Comment: Might also need tack on a `.rename('Count').reset_index()` to get your full desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# data
df = pd.DataFrame({'subject': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4],
                   'bool': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True],
                   'Count': [329232, 73896, 268338, 76424, 186167, 27078, 172417, 113268]})

# answer
df['Per_Subject_Count_Pct'] = df['Count'].div(
    df.groupby('subject')['Count'].transform(lambda x: x.sum()))
print(df)
```

Gives:

```
   subject   bool   Count  Per_Subject_Count_Pct
0        1  False  329232               0.816693
1        1   True   73896               0.183307
2        2  False  268338               0.778328
3        2   True   76424               0.221672
4        3  False  186167               0.873019
5        3   True   27078               0.126981
6        4  False  172417               0.603521
7        4   True  113268               0.396479
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be like this:

***Importing relevant libraries***

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

***Creating a Dataframe*** `df`

```
d = {'subject':[1,1,2,2,3,3],'bool':[False,True,False,True,False,True],
'count':[329232,73896,268338,76424,186167,27078]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

***Using*** `groupby` and `reset_index`

```
table_sum= df.groupby('subject').sum().reset_index()[['subject','count']]
```

***Zip the*** `groupby` ***output and make it as***`dictionary` ***and get the frequency using map***

```
look_1 = (dict(zip(table_sum['subject'],table_sum['count'])))
df['cu_sum'] = df['subject'].map(look_1)
df['relative_frequency'] = df['count']/df['cu_sum']
```

***Output***

```
print(df)

       subject   bool   count  cu_sum  relative_frequency
    0        1  False  329232  403128            0.816693
    1        1   True   73896  403128            0.183307
    2        2  False  268338  344762            0.778328
    3        2   True   76424  344762            0.221672
    4        3  False  186167  213245            0.873019
    5        3   True   27078  213245            0.126981
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#create df
d = {'subject': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], 'bool': [False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True], 'Count': [329232,73896
  ,268338,76424,186167,27078,172417,113268]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

#get sums for each subject group
sums = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['subject'])['Count'].sum().reset_index())
sums.columns = ['subject', 'sums']

#merge sums to original df
df_sums = df.merge(sums, how='left', on='subject')

#calculate percentages for each row
df_sums['percent'] = df_sums['Count']/df_sums['sums']

df_sums
```